# How to set a temporary custom desktop width for a broken display

Tags: resolution, display, screen

I need to temporarily limit the horizontal extension of the Ubuntu environment, because the display is broken and its rightmost quarter is full of vertical lines, making the top panel menus not visible. The screen resolution is 1440x900, so I want the whole graphic environment extend from the left side to only 1000 pixel at the right of it. Is it possible and how? Thank you.